# QTabBar::setTabButton center button

Tags: c++, qt, styles

I'm trying to customize a QTabBar button in Qt/C++ by making it show up as italic and the only way I've found is to use setTabButton and give it a custom widget, which is a QLabel in my case. However, setTabButton's position parameter only has Left or Right as options (See code below). Now it looks weird next to the other tabs which are all centered.

```
tab_bar->setTabButton(index, QTabBar::RightSide,((QWidget*)(tab_label)));
```

Note, there is a stylesheet applied to the whole application... not sure if that would cause the issue to be more apparent.

Stylesheet for that label is:

```
QLabel#GrainButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width: 20px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Any thoughts of how to center this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom widget instead of your QLabel. In this widget you can set a QHBoxLayout with 2 placeholders widgets.

```
QHBoxLayout:
    PlaceHolder( sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed); )
    YourLabel
    PlaceHolder( sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed); )
```

This may place your widget in the center.

Comment: Sadly, I can still only place that custom widget on the left or right side of the tab...

Answer (score 0):

Inherit QProxyStyle and override drawItemPixmap, the pixmap will shown in the center.